# Angular JS ngShow and ngHide

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't figure out why the ngShow and ngHide directives aren't working. Here is a simplified version of the problem.

```
<div id="callFunction" ng-click="myFunction()">content here</div>
<div id="contactInfo" ng-show="showContent">content here</div>
```

In controller

```
$scope.showContent = false;

$scope.myFunction = function() {
    $scope.showContent = true;
}
```

The "contactInfo" div never shows when I click the "callFunction" div.

Comment: you can forget about the controller and do it all in your html: ```ng-click='myvar = !myvar'```. This is maybe also the solution, because you scope/controller is not loaded?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the above code, it must be something else that is causing an issue. Check the browser console for errors, also put a breakpoint on the function and make sure it is being hit when you click the div

Comment: can you re produce the error on fiddle plunker etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is known in the javascript world as "the dot."  The idea is that in javascript, native values are passed by value whereas object values are passed by reference.  Try changing your view to this:

```
<div id="callFunction" ng-click="myFunction()">...</div>
<div id="contactInfo" ng-show="content.Show">...</div>
```

and change your controller to:

```
$scope.content.Show = false;

$scope.myFunction = function() {
    $scope.content.Show = true;
}
```

The reason this would work is because you're now passing an object around and manipulating an object instead of just manipulating a value.  Essentially, think of it as a "sub-scope" problem, where your "div" is spawning its own scope under the view so that variable you're referencing is a native type, it passes by value.  Therefore the function updates the parent value but not the child value.

For more information: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html

Comment: This was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/aesmzz6q

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="theCtrl">

    <div id="callFunction" ng-click="myFunction()">content here</div>
<div id="contactInfo" ng-show="showContent">content here</div>        
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('appName', [])
      .controller('theCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.showContent = false;

        $scope.myFunction = function() {
            $scope.showContent = !$scope.showContent;
        }
      }]);

    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['appName']);
    });
```

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with what you have. Here's a link to a working example.`aesmzz6q`

Answer (score 1):

[This works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10526/). I think your problem might be elsewhere.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div id="callFunction" ng-click="myFunction()">content here</div>
    <div id="contactInfo" ng-show="showContent">content here</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.showContent = false;

    $scope.myFunction = function() {
        $scope.showContent = true;
    }
}
```

I have to include code to allow the JSFiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.11/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div id="callFunction" ng-click="myFunction()">content here</div>
<div id="contactInfo" ng-show="showContent">content here</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I've added a fiddle: http://plnkr.co/edit/S06ufeHI2j5lKs5LxbRT?p=preview

I have also fixed your fiddle there were a number of things wrong http://jsfiddle.net/97nkv1v1/4/

Comment: You didn't select the angular library on the left i've updated it and it works http://jsfiddle.net/z6dd3z2b/1/